# Drag to Corner Scale ImageView Android

Tags: android

I want to implement drag corners to resize imageview but to be honest I do not know how, could anyone assist me with a tutorial or some sort, I would like something that looks like [this](https://github.com/joshdholtz/CropImageView) except it should start with the box around the imageview and by dragging the points it would resize the imageview, I have looked at it but I can not get myself around it, all help will be highly appreciated thank you.

Comment: this is useful? https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Comment: I think it is, its much more clear to understand than the one I was using, let me see if i can get the idea, hopefully i will, thank u

Comment: Have U got any idea??@ChromeLandos